# Play flash files in Android Jelly Bean

Tags: android, flash

We are using WebView to play local SWF files in our Android app.

```
WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_play);
File decfile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/flashplay/temp/test.swf");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(decfile);

if(decfile.exists()){
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.loadUrl(uri.toString());
}
```

The code does not work in Jelly Bean, we have the flash plugin installed and able to play flash videos in Browser. But no luck in getting it played within our app in a WebView in Jelly bean.

Comment: jelly bean and ics not support adobe flash and low versions only support flash like 2.3,2.2,2.1!

Answer (score 1):

First: Flash is no longer supported in since Android 4
Second: Chrome does not support the flash player
Third: You can install (with no guarantee) older flash versions on Android 4 manually and use it in the standard Browser.

Get old versions of flash from adobe here:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

just download the apk and open it. make sure you are trusting apks from other sources.

edit: on my device (samsung galaxy nexus with android 4.1.2) it works just fine.

alternatively there are a dozen other local flash players in the market. you can try to integrate them.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, but i could play flash files in my browser as well as the flash players installed in the tablet. My issue is with playing flash files in WebView within my app. It works in 4.0.1, but the WebView is blacked out in 4.1.1.

Comment: Its main issue with Latest Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 0):

jelly bean and ics not support adobe flash and low versions only support flash like 2.3,2.2,2.1!

Adobe Systems also remove adobe flash app in google play shop!

**"If a device is upgraded from Android 4.0 to Android 4.1, the current version of Flash Player may exhibit unpredictable behaviour, as it is not certified for use with Android 4.1," Adobe said.**

**Flash ICS some device working but,not working all devices properly!**